# using :find or gf on a file with wrong absolute path

Tags: vim

Is it possible to perform *a kind of temporary chroot* in **vim** in order to use `:find` or `gf` on a file with an absolute path ?

e.g, a real world example which prompted me with this question: on an ubuntu system, the file `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/init` sources the `functions` file located at `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/functions` as such:

```
. /scripts/functions
```

How could I jump (using `gf`) to the `functions` file while editing `init` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the visual mode variant of `gf`, and select the correct relative path `scripts/functions` (e.g. with `wviWol`). Then, you only need to `:cd` to the right root dir, and everything should work out fine.